# How to iterate the div in html with different values from getting data from JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json

is there any way that I can use single class and iterate in it with different value from JSON file article[0] and article[1]

I have this in html

````
 <h2 class="title1"></h2><br>
    <div class="author1"></div><br>
    <div class="publishedAt1"></div><br>
    <p class="description1"></p><br>
    <div class="url1"></div><br>

    <h2 class="title2"></h2><br>
    <div class="author2"></div><br>
    <div class="publishedAt2"></div><br>
    <p class="description2"></p><br>
    <div class="url2"></div><br>
```
````

and I am getting this in javascript for iterating the article[0] and article[1].

```
 $('.headerseperator1').text("By Topic");
    $('.title1').text(news.articles[0].title);
    $('.author1').text("By " + news.articles[0].author);
    $('.publishedAt1').text("Published at " + news.articles[0].publishedAt);
    $('.description1').text(news.articles[0].description);
    var urlsrc = '<a href="' + news.articles[0].url + '">Click here for more</a>';
    $('.url1').append(urlsrc) 

    $('.title2').text(news.articles[1].title);
    $('.author2').text("By " + news.articles[1].author);
    $('.publishedAt2').text("Published at " + news.articles[1].publishedAt);
    $('.description2').text(news.articles[1].description);
    var urlsrc = '<a href="' + news.articles[1].url + '">Click here for more</a>';
    $('.url2').append(urlsrc)
```

Comment: use $.each() to iterate through your JSON data and build your topic divs then append them to a wrapper div that you will have under the H2 tag

Answer (score 0):

You can create the html dynamically in a loop and append it to the DOM using `$("#container").append(html);` where "container" is the id of a div that already exists. Here is an example of what I mean.

```js
var json = [{title: "title1", author: "author1", pubAt: "published at 1", desc: "description 1", url: "url 1"}, {title: "title 2", author: "author 2", pubAt: "published at 2", desc: "description 2", url: "url 2"}];

format(json);

function format(json) {
  json.forEach(function(data) {
    var html = "<h2>" + data.title + "</h2>" +
      "<div>" + data.author + "</div>" +
      "<div>" + data.pubAt + "</div>" +
      "<p>" + data.desc + "</p>" +
      "<div>" + data.url + "</div>";
    $("#container").append(html);
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery `eq()` to use a single class name. By example:

```
news.articles.forEach((element, index) => {

    $('.title:eq(' + index + ')').text(element.title);
    $('.author:eq(' + index + ')').text("By " + element.author);
    $('.publishedAt:eq(' + index + ')').text("Published at " + element.publishedAt);
    $('.description:eq(' + index + ')').text(element.description);
    var urlsrc = '<a href="' + element.url + '">Click here for more</a>';
    $('.url:eq(' + index + ')').append(urlsrc) 
});
```

If you prefer, you can change pure JS `forEach` by an jQuery `$.each()`.